Is a system of mass with gravity and external force nonlinear?
The dynamics of an elevator of mass $m$ whose position is defined $y(t)$ upward with gravitational acceleration $g$ acting downward and external force $u(t)$ applied upward is described by
$$u(t) - mg = m\ddot{y}$$
Is this system nonlinear?
I think it is nonlinear because of the constant gravity term and the fact that it can't be written in the state space form $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$
I can substitute $\Delta u = u - u_{eq}$ where $u_{eq} = mg$ which makes
$$\Delta u = m\ddot{y}$$
which is a linear system. Textbooks mention that linearized system is only valid near the equilibrium point. But in this case, it seems to be valid anywhere. So it could have been linear to begin with?

See this.

If you assume the external force is a function of time, as you do, then it is an inhomogeneous linear ODE with respect to the unknown function $y$, $$ y''(t) = \frac{u(t)}{m} - g. $$ However, if you assume the force is a a function of height, $u = u(y)$, then indeed the ODE is nonlinear, $$ y''(t) - \frac{u(y(t))}{m} = mg. $$

As you correctly mentioned, the system cannot be written in state space form and is, due to the summation of a constant term, nonlinear. This can be seen, e.g., observing that the superposition principle (double input leads to double output), which holds for linear systems, does not hold when there is a constant term in the differential equaiton. This can be explained intuitively as follows: consider the state space system $$ \dot x = -x + u$$ $$ y = x, $$
i.e. we have a single state and $A = -1$, $B=1$ and $C=1$ (this is in fact a first order lag). Lets study the steady states that occur after applying a constant input. For $u = 1$, at steady state $\dot x = 0$, we have $y = 1$. For $u=2$, we have $y = 2$. The system seems to fulfill the superposition principle (note that this is not a formal proof).
However, if we consider the same system with a constant summand, i.e. $$ \dot x = -x + u +1 $$ $$ y = x, $$
the superposition principle does not hold. Observe that for $u=1$, we have at steady state $y = 2$, and for $u=2$, we have $y=3$. We just doubled the input, but the output increased by 3/2. We can thus say it is for sure nonlinear with the input and output as defined.
As you noted correctly, when you change the coordinates as above, the system seems to be linear for the whole state space. This is in fact because the constant summand makes that $u = 0$ and $y = 0$ is not a steady state anymore. The constant summand transfers your steady state with $u = 0$ to another output. Shifting the coordinates to this output, you obtain a linear system, since the dynamics (matrix $A$) are linear. After the coordinate shift to obtain a stady state at $u = 0$ and $y_{new} = 0$, you can write the system in state space form, which also shows linearity.
